# Does prepare relate in any way to the prefix 'pre' (meaning 'before')?

Tags: etymology, phrases

Specifically, the phrase *prepare in advance* sounds redundant, as if to say pre-prepare. What is a better phrase to say "make ready beforehand" in the context of putting some ingredients together beforehand?

An example: Combining dry ingredients necessary to make biscuits beforehand, and in a larger quantity, keeping the dry mix in reserve. Later, when making a batch of biscuits, use the prepared-in-advance mix with wet ingredients to make one batch of biscuits.

Is there a better phrase for *prepared in advance*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the *pre-* in *prepare* comes from Latin *prae-*, and means something like "before" or "in advance" (OED, "[prepare, v.](https://oed.com/view/Entry/150447)" and "[pre-, prefix](https://oed.com/view/Entry/149454)").

However, once a word enters English, it does not necessarily retain the sense of its original terms. There is no *pare* word in English that means *to make ready,* as *parare* did in Latin. So *prepare* itself means something like *to make ready*. While logically one has to *prepare* before doing something, English users sometimes add *in advance* or other elements to emphasize preparing *beforehand*. (See also *for sure* in "confirm for sure" - people do this a lot.)

A related phenomenon is adding the prefix *pre-* to forms of *prepare*. The OED (under "pre-, prefix") notes both *pre-prepare* and *pre-prepared* with examples like these:

> 1850   Message from President U.S. 426   It was not commenced; but some stone[s] were pre-prepared, and also the wood-work of a coffer dam.
>
> 1993   Personal Computer World Nov. 442/2   Once programmed, an OLR dials in, grabs what it has been told to and uploads anything else which was pre-prepared offline.

> 1867   Times 6 Sept. 7/4   Why, therefore, should I rob them of the fruit of their labours, and of the toil which they had in preparing those necessarily pre-prepared addresses for the different sections?
>
> 1996   Daily Tel. 29 May 15/4   I am then given her limited, pre-prepared version of the recent events.

Merriam-Webster similarly defines "[preprepared](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/preprepared)" (no hyphen, adjective) as

> : prepared in advance
>
> preprepared ingredients
>
> microwaved a preprepared meal
>
> a preprepared public announcement

Sometimes, there may be a sense that one stage of preparation (preparing ingredients) precedes another stage of preparation (preparing/cooking/microwaving the meal). Other times (the public announcement) *preprepared* seems to emphasize that the preparation was done well in advance, without specifying a step before a preparation.

Whether *pre-prepare* is a better option for you depends on whether you perceive the added *pre-* as emphatic or clarifying or as redundant.